# How to assign values to the tensor matrix according to a given index matrix?

Tags: indexing, pytorch

Here I have a value tensor:

```
index = Tensor([[ 0,  1],
                [ 1,  2],
                [ 4,  1]])
a = Tensor([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
            [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
            [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
b = Tensor([ 5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9.,  10.])
```

How to assign the value in b to a according to the index **in a gentle way without loop**?
Like this:

```
a = Tensor([[ 5.,  6.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
            [ 0.,  6.,  7.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
            [ 0.,  6.,  0.,  0.,  9.,  0.]])
```

I have tried torch.index_put() and torch.scatter(), but unfortunately get a unexpected result.
Much probably, I made a wrong operation.

Comment: Please include der code for the approaches that didn't work

Comment: Please provide copyable example code and imports.

Comment: Your expected output doesn't match the values of tensor *b*, so I'm guessing `a[torch.arange(3).reshape(-1,1), index] = b.reshape(index.shape)`.

Comment: Hi, tensor a and b has same dimension in row. In fact, I expect to place the indexed values of b  to each row of a in same indexed position.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny, I suggest you write an answer with your comment.

Comment: @Ivan I have tried the suggested solution, but get an unexpected answer.

Comment: Which error exactly?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

a.scatter_(1, index, b[index])

PS. ChatGPT yyds!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: “yyds” is the pinyin abbreviation for ” yǒng yuǎn de shén (永远的神)”, meaning “eternal god” or “forever idol”.